# Trying to Label Row and Columns differently

Tags: c#, arrays, label, 2d

I'm creating a spreadsheet using textboxes, however when I'm trying to label the arrays I'm having an issue. Right now, I have managed to Label both Rows and Columns using Nested forloops. However I need to name the columns with Letters. Should I create a separate loops instead of nested?

The Rows, I need to label them in Numbers (which I have achieved through ForLoops. Whilst the Columns I need to label them with Letters, in fact I have created an array for it.

```
{
    Label[,] _arr = new Label[27, 27];

    Label[] _rows = new Label[27];
    Label[] _col = new Label[27] { "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T","U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",};

    TextBox[,] txt = new TextBox[27, 27];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < 27; j++)
                {
                    var textBox = new TextBox()
                    {

                        Name = $"textBox{i}{j}",
                        Width = 50,
                        Height = 20,
                        Location = new Point(50 * j, 20 * i),
                };
                    this.Controls.Add(textBox);                     }
            }

            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _rows.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < _col.Length; j++)
                    {
                        _arr[i, j] = new Label();
                        _arr[i, j].Text = "" + i + "," + j;
                        _arr[i, j].Size = new Size(50, 20);
                        _arr[i, j].Location = new Point(j * 50, i * 20);

                        this.Controls.Add(_arr[i, j]);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Also you have some bracket issues in your code

Comment: Is it a Desktop application?

Comment: I'm doing a winform application